# SCSI connectors with 80-68-50pin adapter on 1995 SCSI-2 controller

Tags: scsi

I have an old SCSI controller "Asus pci sc-200"
I have to connect a 80pin SCSI disk to it

This is the cable

[image]

This is the adapter

[image]

Actually I have connected the white connector to controller and the 68pin black to adapter, but give me only errors, is possible to connect the 50 pin white connector (I have three white connectors in cable) to adapter and then terminate the 68pin connector? Remind in the adapter is connected a 80pin SCA disk.

Comment: “Please help for scsi old connection” is an awful [question title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388112/620615), though I might have written a better one if I understood what the question is.

Comment: I have change it to a long but more "technical" title.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solution found.
First of all remind the controller "Asus SC 200" must be internally terminated removing the jumper near the 50pin internal connector (in this case because we connect the peripherals only on internal controller connector).

[image]

then connect a 50pin connector of cable to the 50-to68-80 adapter, on some adapters the 50pin connector with "plastic cover with broken part"
is without plastic cover (forgive my bad technical english) so you have to found pin1 by yourself, use [this site](https://www.6thplanet.com/store/technical/Info_SCSI_Connectors.html) for refer/help.
Terminate the 68pin connector of the cable (I have attached a scsi tape which has terminator).

Linux part (if use Linux, I don't know on other os)

```
modprobe sym53c8xx
```

Lsscsi report the peripherals

```
lsscsi -g
[0:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      Samsung SSD 870  2B6Q  /dev/sda   -        
[1:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      Samsung SSD 870  2B6Q  /dev/sdb   -        
[2:0:0:0]    disk    Verbatim STORE N GO       1100  /dev/sdc   -        
[3:0:0:0]    disk    SEAGATE  ST3300007LC      D703  /dev/sdd   -        
[3:0:3:0]    tape    HP       C7438A           V601  /dev/st0   -
```

the scsi disk is sdd, the scsi tape is st0.
All fine!

Comment: Every time someone asks me about a SCSI problem, my first response is always "Have you checked the termination?"

Comment: I'm not sure at all, but probably is also the 50pin connector, I explain: the old controller is scsi-2, and has a 50pin only internal connector (modern Adaptec controller has 50pin internal and 68pin internal). Is possible that connect 50 pin to 68pin "port" can cause problem?

Comment: "SCSI is not black magic. There are *sound technical reasons* why you should sacrifice a goat to your SCSI chain every month."